# Reverse JQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

Hi im working with a JQuery slideshow. All my images in my html is on top of each other, and I tried to make my code start with the last image. but it won't work, any ideas?

the original code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = $('#gallery img:first');
    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    current.addClass('show').css({
        opacity: 0.0
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000);

    setInterval('gallery()', 3000);
});

function gallery() {
    //if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
    var current = ($('#gallery img.show') ? $('#gallery img.show') : $('#gallery img:first'));

    //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? current.next() : $('#gallery img:first'));

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    next.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    }).addClass('show').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, 1000).removeClass('show');
}​
```

My reverse code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = $('#gallery img:last');
    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    current.addClass('show').css({
        opacity: 0.0
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000);

    setInterval('gallery()', 3000);
});

function gallery() {
    //if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
    var current = ($('#gallery img.show') ? $('#gallery img.show') : $('#gallery img:last'));

    //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
    var before = ((current.before().length) ? current.before() : $('#gallery img:last'));

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    before.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    }).addClass('show').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, 1000).removeClass('show');
}​
```

Comment: @mprabhat no test page online, sorry

Comment: is it happening that all the time only last item is being shown, hidden ? is that your problem ?

Comment: As the code is now, the slideshow shifts between the last and the second last picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of test page, I added images in ul did this:

```
var before = ((current.prev().length) ? current.prev() : $('#gallery img:last'));
```

This will select the prev image to show, if there are none then again select the last image.

Can you try if this works for you ?

Comment: didn't put the images in an ul, but added the prev and it work ^^

Comment: ah okay, since was doing it with my page just wanted to be explicit, anyways glad it helped you :)